Django Admin updating tabularinline forms
I have a django modeladmin like so:
Class PlanInline(admin.TabularInLine):
      model = Plan
      form = PlanForm

Class SettingsInline(admin.TabularInLine):
      model = Settings
      form = SettingsForm
      
Class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      form = StoreForm
      inlines = (PlanInline, SettingsInline,)
      ....

And I need to pass a value from my Plan form field into my settings form field ss this possible to do from the parent admin form or any method?

should be class not Class
